# How to justify text in PIXI.js

Tags: pixi.js

my question is simple, **is there any way to justify text in PIXI.js ?**

I used word wrap so my text break into lines as I wantedو but I don't know how to make it justified as in css or ...

I searched and as I didn't found any thing I thought it's not possible but if it's not possible **is there any workaround for this problem?**

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

This tool lets you see the options available to text
https://pixijs.github.io/pixi-text-style/

You may also need to anchor the text object to achieve what you want.
textSprite.anchor.x = 0
Will help align to the left. Setting out to 1 will help align to the right

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a powerful tool, but still it  seems there is no option for justify, it can align right or left but how to justify ?

Comment: That's what the anchor on the text object helps you achieve

Comment: Using the anchor aligns the text-object, not the text itself. For example, if you are using word wrap, the text-object will be centered in the parent container, but the text within the text object is still left-aligned.